# Move Outlook Messages Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I'm trying to write a script that downloads the attachments from mail items in a folder that are older than 10 days, save them to my harddrive and then move the mail items to the deleted items folder. So far the attachment download works fine, but when I add in the code to move the emails, it only works on half the emails in my folder. Code shown below. Any help appreciated.

```
$Folder.Items | foreach{
    $Received = New-Object DateTime
    $Received = $_.ReceivedTime

    $howOld = New-Object int
    $howOld = $Today.subtract($Received)
    $howOld = $howOld | select-object -ExpandProperty Days

    $date = $_.ReceivedTime.ToString("MMddyyyy")

    $howOld

    if ($howOld -gt 10){
           #Save Attachment To Folder
           $_.attachments | foreach{
           $fileName = $_.filename
           $split = $fileName.Split('.')
           $fileName = $split[0]
           $fileExtension = $split[1]
           $fileName = $fileName + '_' + $date + '.' + $fileExtension

           $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $fileName))
           }
        #Move to Deleted Folder
        $result = $_.Move($deletedFolder)
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of object is `$Folder`? also you could try to use the `Move-Item` cmdlet instead of using the objects `.Move()` method

Comment: Move-Item gave me an error message. + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand $Folder is a System.__ComObject.

Comment: That is probably because the path is a property of $folder.item and not the item itself. Which type of comobject is it?

Comment: Can you instruct me how to find that out? I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: post the line of code that creates $folder, its probably something like `$Folder = New-object -comobject Shell.Application` or `$Folder = $sh.Namespace($filepath)`

Comment: Update. I Tried changing from a $_.Move to a $_.Delete and I was able to move 3/4 of the items to the deleted folder...Still not reading all mail items though.

Comment: i think you are doing this way too complicated, have you allready identified the line that creates the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to fix the problem by changing the looping structure. Instead of using a foreach i changed to an iterative counter.

```
$emails = $Folder.Items 
For ($i=($emails.count-1);$i -ge 0;$i--)
```

This corrected the problem.

Comment: Glad you found something yourself. I was just wondering why you are using comobjects to do this when there is Get-Item and Move-Item cmdlets and such stuff

Answer (score 0):

You could brute force it also and do

```
while ($mails.count -gt 0)
{
    foreach ($mail in $mails) 
    {
        $mail.move($archive)
    }
    $mails = ($inbox.folders.Item("test")).items
}
```