# Outlook 2013 move mail older than n months to pst

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

I am looking for some kind of automated method to move mail items older than N months from my Exchange inbox (and "Online Archive", also Exchange hosted I believe) into a pst file.  Preferably also preserving the subfolder hierarchy within the Inbox.

I've looked all over SO and google but surprisingly this seems more complicated than it should be.  I'm thinking some kind of script (VBScript, Powershell, VBA) for Outlook 2013 would be best.

The closest thing I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516051/move-outlook-messages-powershell), but it's not exactly what I'm after.

Anyone have any tips, pointers, links, code or even suggestions where to start?

My thought is basic pseudo-code would be:

1. Run Once per day (automated, via some job scheduler)
2. Scan all folders and items with INBOX
3. If item age > N months, move to pst file (create folder if doesn't exist in target

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Use AutoArchive feature in Outlook.

It is capable of moving your items from Exchange **Inbox** folder and its subfolders into local archive PST file, running once per day and move items aged over N months. Set it up in properties of your **Inbox** folder or any other standalone folders:

[image]

Adjust the settings as appropriate.

---

*Maybe there are reasons why you want to do it in another way, but I cannot find anything like that in the question as it is currently asked.*

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on Exchange server and I believe we have a GPO that hides the autoarchive ability (we also have the "Online Archive" folder, which might also be the reason why AutoArchive isn't available.